# relationship between Zorn's lemma and Axiom of Completeness

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, axioms

For me , they look like they are 'similar' to each other , just that one is used in set and another one is used in numbers. Can anyone tell me is there any relationship between Zorn's Lemma and Axiom of Completeness ?

Comment: The Axiom of Completeness being what?  Any nonempty subset of the reals that is bounded above has a least upper bound?

Comment: @GEdgar: The Axiom of COmpleteness of real number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no relationship except that both assert the existence of certain elements.

Zorn's lemma is an axiom which guarantees that under certain conditions there are maximal elements; the completeness axiom guarantees that every bounded set has a least upper bound.

Whereas the completeness axiom is less of an axiom and more of a property of the real numbers stemming from their definition via Dedekind cuts; Zorn's lemma is actually needed in order to prove the existence of maximal elements in some partially ordered sets.

Answer (score 0):

Their only relationship is that they are both familiar "topological" properties of objects, so that the same "completeness" idea appears in different contexts. Zorn's Lemma is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice in Set Theory. The Axiom of Completeness for real numbers is thus independent of Zorn's Lemma, since they are axioms chosen in different domains.